# Mathematical notation in Latex

Tags: latex

is there a way to write in Latex the following?

> ```
>   I(.)
> ```

but centering the point? I need to use this notation in a mathematical equation.

Thank you in advance

Best

Comment: There is a dedicated site for [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
I(\cdot)
\]

\[
I(\bullet)
\]


\end{document}
```